Why does calling `await asyncio.sleep` run un awaited tasks, but `time.sleep` doesn't?
I have this code snippet
import asyncio
import time


async def put_stuff_into_queue(stuff_into_queue: list[str], queue: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    for stuff in stuff_into_queue:
        await queue.put(stuff)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"end time: {time.strftime('%X')}")


async def process_stuff_from_queue(queue: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        stuff: str = await queue.get()
        print(stuff)


async def main() -> None:
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    stuff_into_queue = ["this", "is", "a", "simple", "test"]

    print(f"start time: {time.strftime('%X')}")

    asyncio.create_task(put_stuff_into_queue(stuff_into_queue, queue))  # this line is never awaited
    asyncio.create_task(process_stuff_from_queue(queue))  # this line is never awaited

    await asyncio.sleep(8)  # with this line, the previous two lines seems to be running
    # time.sleep(8)  # if I comment out the previous line and instead use this line, then all the tasks don't run


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

The output I receive with the code as it is above is
start time: 15:54:38
this
is
a
simple
test
end time: 15:54:43

Process finished with exit code 0

If I run with time.sleep(8) instead of await asyncio.sleep(8), then my output is
start time: 15:59:09
this

Process finished with exit code 0

The console output this occurs after sleeping for 8 seconds, so I presume it has something to with the unawaited tasks executing a single iteration once asyncio.run(main()) is done? I am not entirely sure why I only get one iteration, or why I even get an iteration of Task event loop.
Why are the two un-awaited tasks running perfectly when I have await asyncio.sleep(8), but not when I have time.sleep(8)? Does it have something to do with GIL when doing time.sleep where it somehow blocks the main loop flow?


Why are the two un-awaited tasks running perfectly when I have await asyncio.sleep(8), but not when I have time.sleep(8)?

Because that's how asyncio works: calling await is what yields execution back to the scheduler so that it can run other async tasks. When you call time.sleep, you're never calling await, so other async tasks never get the chance to run.

Yes but I am only awaiting asyncio.sleep(8), my IDE is complaining that I am never awaiting the two previous tasks, but they somehow still gets executed. Is it because doing one await keyword in my code make asyncio look at all tasks that are defined within my current scope, and then executes all of them at once, similar to asyncio.gather ?

@wordhydrogen You've never told your code "Wait until these tasks are complete." That doesn't mean you've told it "Don't run these tasks when time is available."

Calling await is what allows the async scheduler to run other async tasks. It doesn't just run the particular thing on which you are await-ing. It is a signal that says, "I am done for now, let something else run."

I see, so basically asyncio.create_task creates tasks that are put into the event loop, and they only run when control is given back to the event loop, which in my case the control is given back to the event loop whenever I use the await keyword inside main function? I guess my confusion came because I thought asyncio.create_task would create tasks like threads and just run regardless of if I wrote await asyncio.sleep or time.sleep, i.e. I was hoping time.sleep would also give control back to the event loop

time.sleep is entirely synchronous code. In essence it's basically a while loop at the current point of execution, blocking anything else from happening. The loop only gets control when you say so, mainly by awaiting something non-blocking like asyncio.sleep.
